# AutoPrefixer adding an odd extra condition to my resolution-based media query

Tags: sass, media-queries, autoprefixer

I'm setting up a SCSS mixin to automate the media query syntax for high-definition screens. My SCSS is compiled via Codekit with AutoPrefixer being applied after compilation. The mixin includes multiple media queries, each targeting a different screen resolution. The syntax I'm using in each media query is as follows:

```
@media only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 4/5),
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
    only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
    only screen and (min-resolution: 1.25dppx),
    only screen and (min-resolution: 120dpi) {
        // my styles
    }
```

This syntax is repeated several times, with the numbers adjusted as needed in order to target different resolutions. It compiles fine, and after AutoPrefixer works it's magic, I'm left with the following compiled output:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), 
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), 
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), 
only screen and (min-resolution: 1.25dppx), 
only screen and (min-resolution: 120dpi) {
      // my styles
      }
```

which is almost identical to the input, aside from the Opera prefix having been removed. Great. EXCEPT in one case. For reasons I cannot fathom, when it comes to my x2 ratio code block, AutoPrefixer is inserting a weird extra line. Here's my compiled input **before** being AutoPrefixed:

```
@media only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2 / 1), 
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx), 
only screen and (min-resolution: 194dpi) {
  // my styles
}
```

And here's the AutoPrefixed output:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx), 
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.0208333333333335), 
only screen and (min-resolution: 194dpi) {
  // my styles
}
```

You can see the issue: AutoPrefixer has added a second -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio condition with the weird value of 2.0208333333333335. The media query already has a -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio condition, so this extra one is in direct conflict with it. And the weird thing is that it is ONLY doing this on the x2 query. The other queries, all of which have the same copied-and-pasted syntax, do not get this weird extra rule.

Can anyone explain this and tell me how to avoid it (other than not using AutoPrefix).

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. It was pilot error.

I realised that the value of the 'min-resolution' condition should have been 192 not 194. Evidently AutoPrefixer uses that value to calculate the -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio condition, and Those extra 2px were causing the it to calculate a value slightly greater than 2 -- and since that differed to the earlier declared -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio value, that was added to the conditions as an additional line.

Moral: check your maths.